# Why does Google Chrome freeze every time I upload a file?

Tags: google-chrome, elementaryos

Every time I upload a file to Google Chrome, the browser freezes. The file *is* uploaded, but I have to close Chrome and open again to see it.

What is this bug? How can I solve it?

PS: The browser freezes no matter where I upload a file; be it Facebook, Gmail, or whatever.

Comment: Open Task Manager. Go to the Performance Tab. Upload a file in Chrome. Does the CPU utilisation increase?

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 there's not Task Manager in elementary

Comment: This happens on a managed computer?

Comment: @JohnSmith There is System Monitor which is - in layman's terms only - the equivalent of Windows' Task Manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What got it fixed for me:

1- Open terminal and switch to root:

```
sudo -i
```

2- remove `pantheon-filechooser-module`:

```
rm /etc/profile.d/pantheon-filechooser-module.sh
```